# pycharm - Does Pycharm have debugging mode for API debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I use Pycharm for my Python written API and wondering if there is kind of debugging mode in Pycharm that when I make http.get request from my browser to this API it can run in debugging mode so that I can check code line by line (as well as creating breaking point...)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the debugging mode is available in Pycharm also available in Community Edition.
You have to make configuration of your server and directly run the API with Pycharm button

Kindly follow the JetBrains guide links:

1. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-code.html
2. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html
3. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: I know there is debugging button in Pycharm that I can debug code internally, but now what I'm looking for is to make a api call from browser and the called api in Pycharm running in debugging mode.

Comment: Yes, you can setup the configuration in pycharm debugger with respect to the starting point of your application
or you can also set remote debugging
if your application is running at 5000 port, and on localhost
then you can setup the remote debugger in the pycharm by adding the above configuration

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more detail? I see there is Built-in server under Debugger, and there is port 63442, and a button 'can accept external connections'. is this the one you refer to? I don't see anything about remote debugger.

Comment: Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html